# PowerShell two dimensional array for counting data

Tags: powershell

I have data which I read from files:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
   $data = Get-FocalLength $file
}
```

The $data will have value like this:

```
20 mm
15 mm
7 mm
20 mm
16 mm
...
```

And so on.

After the loop, I want to count how many occurrences per data, **sorted**. For example, like this:

```
20 mm : 2
17 mm : 15
15 mm : 1
```

What is the simplest way to do this in PowerShell?

Comment: You could use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.4) to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Is `$data` an array of strings or is it a single string and `$files` is the array of strings?

Comment: $data is just a single string.

Comment: so the `foreach` loop is not needed in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) mentioned in a comment, [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.4) is an easy way to count appearances of strings then you can use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.4) with a [calculated expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.4#sort-object) on that result. The expression is meant to remove any non digit and the coerce that into `int` for a proper sorting.

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Get-FocalLength $file |
        Group-Object -NoElement |
        Sort-Object { $_.Name -replace '\D' -as [int] } -Descending
}

# Using `$data` from your question as example, you should get:
#
# Count Name
# ----- ----
#     2 20 mm
#     1 16 mm
#     1 15 mm
#     1 7 mm
```

Another option is to use a hashtable for counting the appearances and then the same sorting expression on the `.Key` property. If you want to have an output exactly as you're showing in you question, a bit more work is required:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $result = @{}; $len = 0
    foreach ($i in Get-FocalLength $file) {
        $result[$i] += 1
        if ($i.Length -ge $len) {
            $len = $i.Length
        }
    }

    $result.GetEnumerator() |
        Sort-Object { $_.Key -replace '\D' -as [int] } -Descending |
        ForEach-Object { "{0, $len} : {1}" -f $_.Key, $_.Value }
}

# Using `$data` from your question as example, you should get:
#
# 20 mm : 2
# 16 mm : 1
# 15 mm : 1
#  7 mm : 1
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the question (I updated). The $data is obtained individually, therefore foreach is needed.

Comment: @Kawaii-Hachii see my update, the logic is still the same, just goes inside the loop